# Differentiating and simplifying matrices

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

Hi I was struggling to maximise this function wrt to $x$. $B$ is a weight matrix.

$\\y_{i} = \binom{y_{1i}}{y_{2i}}.$

Function: 
$\left [\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i} y_{i} - \binom{1}{2}x  \right ]'  B  \left [\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i} y_{i} - \binom{1}{2}x  \right ]$,

First Derivative Answer:$\ (1,2) B \left [\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i} y_{i}  - \binom{1}{2}x  \right ] = 0$

I tried using this rule:

[image]

Comment: Write the objective function using only matrices and vectors. No sums allowed. Once you reach that stage, everything is easier. And the "rule" only applies when $A$ is symmetric.

Comment: Is $\begin{pmatrix} 1\\2\end{pmatrix}$ a vector?

Comment: Then $x$ is a row vector?